# how do I upload a local image file to firebase storage? (With Javascript, React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, firebase-storage

I am developing in a reaction project environment created by create-react-app.

I want to upload the image to firebase storage by accessing the local path directly without selecting the image to be uploaded by the user.

The examples of image upload on the Internet are all these types of code.

```
const onSubmit = (event) => {
    const image = event.target.files[0];
    const storageRef = storage.ref("images/"); 
  const imagesRef = storageRef.child(image.name);
    const upLoadTask = imagesRef.put(image);
}

return (
    <form onSubmit={onSubmit}>
      <input type="file" />
      <button onClick={onSubmit}>upload</button>
    </form>
);
```

However, I would like to upload an image to firebase storage without using `<input type="file" />`!

The format I want is to access the image path of the local repository and import the file as follows:

```
const image = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/myImage.png`;
const storageRef = storage.ref("images/"); 
const imagesRef = storageRef.child(image);
const upLoadTask = imagesRef.put(image);
```

How do you create these codes?

Other than that, how can I upload images drawn with `html canvas` to firebase storage?

The format I want is to access the image path of the local repository and import the file as follows:

```
const image = `${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/assets/myImage.png`;
const storageRef = storage.ref("images/"); 
const imagesRef = storageRef.child(image);
const upLoadTask = imagesRef.put(image);
```